# Optimize a xslt path to access a concrete node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am rookie using xslt and I would want to optimize a xslt file. I have a doubt about how to access to a node... how should I do to make my xslt faster:

```
node()[name()='NameOfNode']/node()[name()='NameOfSubNode']/node()[name()='NameOfSubNode2']
```

or simply:

```
NameOfNode/NameOfSubNode/NameOfSubNode2
```

The first one sounds like it needs to do more operations (node() and name()), but maybe it is the same... I don´t know.

Comment: Semantically, they're the same. Optimizing is processor-dependent and you would have to run tests to see if it makes a difference. Offhand, I see no reason why the more complex expression should be faster, and readability is important too.

Comment: I would first suggest to learn XPath to write precise and clear XPath expressions with a clear understanding of semantics before I worry about performance. Your first attempt is not necessarily selecting the same nodes as your second, as a step like `NameOfSubNode2` can only select an element node while a step like `node()[name()='NameOfSubNode2']` would also select a processing instruction with name `NameOfSubNode2`. And the use of `name()` in case of namespaces might also give different results.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k I have been doing some test and the result is that the most simple is better `NameOfNode/NameOfSubNode/NameOfSubNode2` at least on my cpu.

Comment: That's hardly surprising. But when I said "processor-dependent" I meant the XSLT engine (e.g. Xalan, Saxon, libxslt), not your CPU.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen I am learning all about the xslt (including xpath) on the fly... but in this case the second option is better. This one is faster and it generates the same transformation than the first, so... in this case (without namespaces), it seems that both are getting the same nodes. Thanks.

Comment: @michael.hor257k ah!!! I didn´t get you... haha I am using libxslt. Thanks Michael :)

Comment: If you're that new to XSLT then you really shouldn't be worrying about performance yet. Get to know what you can do with the language and how to produce readable working code first. You can generally assume that simpler expressions will be faster, because compiler-writers optimize the constructs that are used most often. (If your two expressions were precisely equivalent, then the optimizer would probably turn one into the other. In fact there are edge cases involving namespaces, processing instruction nodes, etc, where they produce different results.)

Comment: @EloyFernándezFranco you should also be aware that libxslt is a very old implementation of a very old version of the language. It's still widely used, because it's a very well-engineered piece of software, but in the end your performance is more important that the machine's performance, and you will be several times more productive if you use a more modern version of the language.